# Extract hashed user password in Azure SQL DB

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I need to get hashed passwords of users in Azure SQL DB (Single Database - Managed Instance). Users exist only on DB and not on server. Users were created with:

`Create user xyz with password = 'abc'`

I have tried LoginProperty function but it does not work in Azure SQL DB.

Comment: Hi, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Comment: Leon Yue, Your answer does not solve the problem. Kindly take a look at my comment on your anser.

Answer (score 1):

this option does not help with Azure SQL Database(PAAS) as i recieved the error: Keyword or statement option 'hashed' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

Azure SQL does not have this option, it is deprecated. Not sure how a migration will be performed if password is not known of the account.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this document: [sys.sql_logins (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-logins-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15), it supports Azure SQL database and returns one row for every SQL Server authentication login.

[image]

Run this query in your master DB, you can see the user `password_hash`.

For example, I created a login sagarreadonly' in master db,  then created the user 'sagarreadonly' in my SQL database.

I can get the user's hashed password. Here is code:

```
use master
select name, password_hash from sys.sql_logins where name='sagarreadonly'
```

Screenshots:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Leon Yue, your answer is not what I required. I specifically mentioned that user is database level user and not present at server level. Your solution works only for server level user.